# Collapse similar case statements in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Is there an elegant way to do something like the following example using just one case statement?

```
foobar match {
    case Node(Leaf(key, value), parent, qux) => {
        // Do something with parent & qux
    }
    case Node(parent, Leaf(key, value), qux) => {
        // Do something with parent & qux (code is the same as in the previous case)
    }
    // other cases
}
```

For an understanding of what is going on here: `foobar` is a node of a binary tree, and I match the cases when one of the node's ancestors is a `Leaf` node. These are the classes used:

```
abstract class Tree
case class Node(left: Tree, right: Tree, critBit: Int) extends Tree
case class Leaf(key: String, value:String) extends Tree
```

Comment: Maybe matching 'other cases' first would help?

Comment: Not sure what algorithm you're implementing, but I've seen a similar situation and I think you're recursing "too late" :) Don't look too much in the structure of a `Node`, let the recursive call deal with a `Leaf`.

Comment: You are trying to reduce the amount of redundant code across some case statements. The only way you will be able to do that is push your common code into methods that get invoked on `parent` and `qux`. You can't squash the case matching together.

Comment: @BobDalgleish : You can (google 'scala pattern alternative'). Unfortunately  it is extremely limited (in Scala) , as you can't bind a variable in such patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom extractor to abstract the matching part away from the logic part:

```
object Leafed {
  def unapply(tree: Tree) = tree match {
    case Node(Leaf(_, _), parent, qux) => Some((parent, qux))
    case Node(parent, Leaf(_, _), qux) => Some((parent, qux))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

And then you can define methods like this:

```
def doSomething(tree: Tree): Int = tree match {
  case Leafed(parent, qux) => qux
  case _ => -100
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
scala> val leaf = Leaf("foo", "bar")
leaf: Leaf = Leaf(foo,bar)

scala> doSomething(leaf)
res7: Int = -100

scala> doSomething(Node(leaf, Node(leaf, leaf, 5), 10))
res8: Int = 10

scala> doSomething(Node(Node(leaf, leaf, 5), leaf, 10))
res9: Int = 10
```

Otherwise you're out of luck—as Marth notes above, pattern alternatives aren't going to help you here.